# operação com data e prazos SQL_SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

tenho uma tabela no BD que tem uma coluna chamada prazo.

nessa coluna eu tenho a informações do prazo em meses ex.: 10, 6, 12, 14....

eu precisaria calcular para saber a data final de cada prazo.

no excel eu usaria:

`=data(ano;mes+prazo;dia)`

e ele traria a data referente ao ultimo pagamento deste prazo.

como fazer no sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sql você poderia utilizar a função DATEADD. Ela possui os seguintes parâmetros:

DATEADD (parte da data, número para adicionar , data )

No seu caso DATEADD(month (Seu prazos estão definidos em meses);prazo;data)

```
Ex:

select DATEADD(month,5,GETDATE())

select DATEADD(month,5,'01/01/2021')
```

Recomendo a leitura da documentação abaixo:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15